# Need help in pandas date time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I need help in converting the date in a pandas Dataframe which is in the format 20200125 and change it to 2020-01-25.

when executing with the code -

```
df['document_create_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['document_create_date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

The output I get is in the format -> `1970-01-01 00:00:00.020200125`

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
Maybe you have to convert your column from int to string before:

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'document_create_date': [20200125]})

df['document_create_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['document_create_date'].astype(str))
```

---

You have not the right format. You have to specify the source format not the target format:

```
df['document_create_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['document_create_date'],format='%Y%m%d')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  document_create_date
0           2020-01-25
```

Or let pandas determine the right format:

```
df['document_create_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['document_create_date'])
```

Comment: I think the issue is not reproducible without more information about the input data

Comment: @RJAdriaansen. I'm pretty sure my update it's the right answer. If 20200125 is an integer, you get the date 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020200125. So the issue is reproducible.

Comment: @Anakxxx. Does it solve your problem?